# iPhone App:Selected text in uiwebview replace with some special character

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, encoding

In my iPhone App I have load .html file in uiwebview, when I am highlighting below text

[image]

```
1.   The income statement.
```

with code

> NSString *selection = [self.wvNotes
>   stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.getSelection().toString()"];

In log it gives me text as

[image]

1.\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0 The income statement.

It is replacing space with some `\u00a0`. what could be wrong?

Comment: If your indentation is with space i don't see any issue. What special character are you referring?

Comment: @tiguero  I have edited my Question Pls see it again

Comment: this is the unicode of non breaking space so again i don't see an issue: you are getting back a unicode string

Comment: thanks for comment. Here instead of unicode how to get string in its original form with space as it is appearing in web view

Comment: did u write your NSLog like this: NSLog(@"%@", selection) ?

Comment: ya if I write like this it gives me log ". . "(exactly as shown in question not as here - full stop) and If I print value in console with print description it gives value with unicode

Comment: isn't my answer correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *selection = [self.wvNotes stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.getSelection().toString()"];
```

is giving you a string that is encoded in unicode. As you have seen if you do an NSLog on this string it will print the non breaking space (`.` for the unicode string `\u00a0`). If you don't want those you can replace the unicode string with the space string `" "`

```
 NSString* stringToConvert = @"1.\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0 Test";
 stringToConvert = [stringToConvert stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\u00a0" withString:@" "];
 // This will print "1.     Test"
 NSLog(stringToConvert);
```